# Error Swift_TransportException when send YiiMail

Tags: php, email, yii

My website uses Yii Framework, I use YiiMail to send mail, mail is sent well on localhost but can not is sent on live host.

When send mail, I get the error:

Swift_TransportException
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "mail@gmail.com" using 2 possible authenticators

My config:

```
    'mail' => array(
        'class' => 'ext.yii-mail.YiiMail',
        'transportType' => 'smtp', // change to 'php' when running in real domain.
        'viewPath' => 'application.views.mail',
        'logging' => true,
        'dryRun' => false,
        'transportOptions' => array(
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'mymail@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'pass',
            'port' => '465',
            'encryption' => 'ssl',
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Do you unlock your account for access through other sites?

Comment: Check precisely how your hosting service recommends setup up for mail/smtp server. This error has nothing to do with SwiftMailer neither PHP framework. Check what port are you connecting to, proper authentication type, if you have correctly configured server for accepting emails, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of server you are using ?

if linux(centos) then try these commands

$ service httpd restart

$ setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on

then try to send emails.